# Sign PDF document and get the pdf as bytes or stream

Tags: java, javascript, pdf, applet, itext

I'm working on sign pdf document using Itext in Java .

it works fine but can i sign the pdf Document without save the file ?

here's part of the code :

```
 FileOutputStream os = (FileOutputStream) readWriteFiles(2);
        System.out.println("FileOutputStream created");

        if (os == null) {
            System.out.println("Operation canceled by the user. He chose to not overwrite existing file.");
            return;
        }

         PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0', null, true);
       // PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature;

        System.out.println("stamper created");


        /* Creating the appearance */
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
        appearance.setReason(reason);
        appearance.setLocation(location);

        /* Creating the signature */
        ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();

        ExternalSignature signature =
                new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm, provider);

        System.out.println(signature.toString() + "\n\n\n" + appearance.toString());
        MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, signature, chain,
                null, null, null, 0, subfilter);
```

OS is include the path of the output pdf file .
and when i try to put the os as null it didn't sign .

my Question is how to sign the pdf without save the output pdf file ?

and how can i get the PDF as bytes or stream in order to use it in javascript ( it's an applet ) ?

Comment: *when i try to put the os as null it didn't sign* - well, if you neither supply an output stream nor a temp file position (the other `null` in your call), how do you expect iText to return a signed file to you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation

public static PdfStamper createSignature(PdfReader reader,
                                         OutputStream os,
                                         char pdfVersion)
                                  throws DocumentException,
                                         IOException

You can give any OutputStream you want, so I suggest you do

```
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, output, '\0', null, true);
```

Then you can retrieve the content of output as an array of bytes (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html)